# Python Image file not imported while importing another file in first file

Tags: python, image, tkinter, import

I have created a File for Details window (detaildisplaywin.py) which shows a button to add/edit user and Using the button widget of tkinter to call a function to call another function in another file userwindow.py.
The file is getting imported successfully but the image is not displayed. However the function is running successfully till the root.title.
Not sure why this is happening. Any suggestion would be great help
Thanks

Attaching code and ss for reference

File 1 : detaildisplaywin.py

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from userwindow import *


def windowcallingfunc():
    userwindow.mainuserwindow()

def datawindow():
    userwin = tk.Tk()
    userwin.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
    userwin.grid_columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
    userwin.geometry("1300x768")
    userwin.configure(bg='#1c143c')
    userwin.state('zoomed') 
    user_code_label = tk.Label(userwin, text="Enter Number", font = ("Times",15), bg = '#1c143c', fg = 'white')
    user_code_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = (10,0), pady = (10,0))
    user_code_entry = tk.Entry(userwin, font = ("Times", 18))
    user_code_entry.grid(row =1, column = 0, padx = (10,0), pady = (0,0))
    user_code_entry.focus_set()
    user_code_submit = tk.Button(userwin, text = "Submit", font =("Times", 12), fg = "black", bg = "white")
    user_code_submit.grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = (10,0))
    def on_enter(e):
        user_add_edit_btn.config(background='black', foreground= "white")
    def on_leave(e):
        user_add_edit_btn.config(background= 'SystemButtonFace', foreground= "blue")   
    add_user_frame = tk.Frame(userwin)
    add_user_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 10, sticky = tk.SE, padx = (0, 10), pady = (10,0))
    user_add_edit_btn = tk.Button(add_user_frame, text = "Add/Edit New User", font = ("Times New Roman", 18), bg = "white", command = windowcallingfunc)
    user_add_edit_btn.pack()
    user_add_edit_btn.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
    user_add_edit_btn.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)
    
    userwin.mainloop()
    
datawindow()
```

File 2 userwindow.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

def mainuserwindow():
    mainuserwindow.root = tk.Tk()
    mainuserwindow.root.geometry("1280x768")
    mainuserwindow.root.configure(bg='#1c143c')
    mainuserwindow.root.title("MainUserWin")

    userwiniconimage = Image.open('Logo.png')
    userwinicon_resize= userwiniconimage.resize((300,250))
    userwiniconph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(userwinicon_resize)
    mainuserwindow.root.iconphoto(False, userwiniconph)
    
    logoimageuserwin = Image.open('userwinlogo.png')
    resized_imageuserwin= logoimageuserwin.resize((300,250))
    phuserwin = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_imageuserwin)
    imageframeuserwin = tk.Frame(mainuserwindow.root)
    imageframeuserwin.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)
   
    userwinimagelabel1 = tk.Label(imageframeuserwin, image = phuserwin, borderwidth = 0, bg = "#1c143c", bordercolor = None)
    userwinimagelabel1.pack()
    mainuserwindow.root.mainloop()
```

**The code is running perfectly and showing all images if I run userwindow.py file itself**
screenshot

[Image showing mainuserwin called from detaildisplaywin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1i8U.png)

[Image showing mainuserwin showing logo called in its own window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17xBW.png)

Comment: Any suggestion would be great help . Thanks

Comment: Your program can't have two main windows (tk.Tk) at the same time.  Take a look at using tk.Toplevel for one of your windows

Comment: @JimRobinson Thanks for quick response. This really helped a lot.